# ¿An error occurred during local report processing.. InnerException: System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, reporting

tengo la siguiente excepción cuando estoy creando reportviewer , traigo la información de una base de datos sql mediante un store procedure y cuando trata de render al reporte pasa lo siguiente,

Message: An error occurred during local report processing..   InnerException: System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.     at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Int32 width, Int32 height, PixelFormat format)     at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Image original, Int32 width, Int32 height)     at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Image original)     at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.PDFWriter.Process32bppArgbImage(StringBuilder sb, StringBuilder imageContent, PDFImage image)     at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.PDFWriter.ProcessImage(PDFImage image)     at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.PDFWriter.EndPage()     at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.Renderer.ProcessPage(RPLReport rplReport, Int32 pageNumber, FontCache sharedFontCache, List`1 glyphCache)     at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.PDFRenderer.Render(Report report, NameValueCollection deviceInfo, Hashtable renderProperties, CreateAndRegisterStream createAndRegisterStream)     at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.RendererBase.Render(Report report, NameValueCollection reportServerParameters, NameValueCollection deviceInfo, NameValueCollection clientCapabilities, Hashtable& renderProperties, CreateAndRegisterStream createAndRegisterStream).   StackTrace:    at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.InternalRender(String format, Boolean allowInternalRenderers, String deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, CreateAndRegisterStream createStreamCallback, Warning[]& warnings)     at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.InternalRender(String format, Boolean allowInternalRenderers, String deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, String& mimeType, String& encoding, String& fileNameExtension, String[]& streams, Warning[]& warnings)     at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.Render(String format, String deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, String& mimeType, String& encoding, String& fileNameExtension, String[]& streams, Warning[]& warnings)     at AppSingless472.App_Tools.PdfCreatorBase.GetArryBytesPdfConFoto(Int32 IdGuiaSoporte)     at AppSingless472.WebApiController.SoporteController.SoporteEntregaConFoto(FormData formData, HttpRequestMessage request).   TargetSite: Void InternalRender(System.String, Boolean, System.String, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.PageCountMode, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces.CreateAndRegisterStream, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Warning[] ByRef).

El siguiente error , pasa ocasionalmente y en produccion (azure me da la siguiente excepcion) System.OutOfMemoryException
Message An exception was thrown by a TaskScheduler. Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. 
Exception type  System.OutOfMemoryException 
Failed method   MultipartDataMediaFormatter.Converters.HttpContentToFormDataConverter+d__0.MoveNext

ya llevo varios dias con este error , y no logro solucionarlo

muchas gracias por la atencion.

Comment: Como defines el parametro del reporte desde codigo ? Igualmente hay algo raro porque un `Parameter is not valid` no tiene nada que ver con un `OutOfMemoryException`

Comment: @LeandroTuttini Hola , lo defino asi con un localreport , consulto en el SP y luego hago un render con 

  byte[] bytes = localReport.Render(
                   "PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension,
                   out streamids, out warnings);